# User-friendly migration of data between instances of an application

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-migration

We have a web-based system that is essentially a survey application.
Up until now we've been loading new surveys in directly into the database (as flyway migrations). This is obviously not tenable long-term, and we need to put the power to create new surveys into the hands of the admin users. One aspect of this is adding the UI so that admin users can create new surveys.

However, we want the admin users to create and test any new surveys in a test environment first before letting it loose in production. As these surveys are complex, there is a real risk that a survey that is setup in a test environment is subtly different from how someone does the setup in the production environment. My aim is to remove this risk.

My question pertains to the technical mechanism(s) we could implement so that the admin users can, on a self-service basis, "migrate" surveys from their test environment (where they've done all of their testing and verification) to the production environment - such that we have a high confidence that the migrated survey(s) will be setup identically. Applications like Moodle already have this sort of functionality built-in.

I've considered:

- Allowing users to create a checksum of a survey (perhaps based on the hashcode of all the elements) so they can know that the surveys across the two environments are identical. The issue then is that it would be annoying to try and find the exact difference between the surveys on the two instances.
- Writing a UI that dumps raw SQL as the export and allowing these users to just splatting it into the production database, but it's incredibly bad from so many perspectives
- Constructing our own domain-specific language that describes these surveys - but writing an input/output parser just seems so complex
- Dumping the data to JSON (given that it's a RESTful web app, most of this is already done) and sucking it back in

At this stage, I'm leaning towards the JSON method, but would be keen to hear any other ideas or libraries that we could easily integrate into a Spring Boot app that would assist with this process.

Comment: Create the survey in production and give them a status (DRAFT, PUBLISHED, CLOSED). When an admin user logs in it can test the DRAFT survey and once satisfied PUBLISH it. No need to copy anything or migrate environments.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, solving that kind of problem by introducing independent instances sounds like a terrible idea: Not only the migration part is tricky. You will have to ensure compatibility at all times. Imagine an admin uses an outdated version or does not configure *his instance* correctly (every admin's dream). Even if the migration itself produces no errors the results may be different in the end (and that's what you actually want to avoid).

As I understand it, you currently look at a survey as a bulk of raw information that somehow appears in your database and then gets displayed by the application. From that point of view you obviously can't tell the difference between a test survey and a production survey.

That's why you really should extend your model!

There is much more than just a survey. There is a *survey draft* and/or a *survey preview area*, a *survey creation process* that users go through, a process that spins of a production survey from a draft, etc.

If you add those concepts to your application a use case like the one you described should be easy to implement (you already mentioned a planned UI, right?).

Hope I could help you. Sorry, I know it doesn't exactly answer your question.